# Liferay: Default Language by Site

Tags: localization, internationalization, liferay

I have one portal and several communities (LR 6.1 - sites). The communities allocate several regions with different languages, hence I would like set different default languages for each community.

Is it possible to set default language by site?

I need it for CMS requirements: every site has a own default language for content. For example site in Germany must have germany as default language, and site in Spain have a spanish as default language and so on.

[image: Web Content Default Language]

Comment: What do you want to achieve at once?

Comment: See my question, I have update it.

Comment: I don't know if you have found the answer to your question by now or not, but you don't need to have default language set for every site version in order to have the CMS in that language. Once for example you change to a language, the Control Panel changes into that language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there might be a way based on how you organize your editors: The default language for web content is based on the current language (e.g. the default language) of the user. Typically german users might have their language set to german, in order to read the german content version, no?

Alternatively you'd have to customize Liferay (e.g. the webcontent editor) and manually set the default language based on some property in the current site - this might be stored as custom field aka expando. This way it will truly be based on the site that content is being created in, but this might conflict with the current user's expectation: What do they set their default language for when the editor doesn't honor this?

Still - in your case the expectation might even be what you describe, so it's a valid option.

Is this level of detail enough?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware that configuration setting for default language per site (if you mean   community/organization...) exists.

For entire portal you have "Default Language" option under

```
Control panel -> Portal settings -> Display settings
```

But if you don't have your language there, or you want to remove/add some languages you can configure that in `portal-ext.properties`. For example

```
locales=hr_HR,en_US
```

EDIT (more info about bug mentioned in comment)

If you take a look at **com.liferay.portal.service.impl.CompanyLocalServiceImpl**

```
public void updatePreferences(long companyId, UnicodeProperties properties)
    throws PortalException, SystemException {

    PortletPreferences preferences = PrefsPropsUtil.getPreferences(
        companyId);

    try {
        String newLocales = properties.getProperty(PropsKeys.LOCALES);

        if (newLocales != null) {
            String oldLocales = preferences.getValue(
                PropsKeys.LOCALES, StringPool.BLANK);

            if (!Validator.equals(oldLocales, newLocales)) {
                validateLocales(newLocales);

                LanguageUtil.resetAvailableLocales(companyId);
            }
        }

    ...
}


protected void validateLocales(String locales) throws PortalException {
    String[] localesArray = StringUtil.split(locales, StringPool.COMMA);

    for (String locale : localesArray) {
        if (!ArrayUtil.contains(PropsValues.LOCALES, locale)) {
            throw new LocaleException();
        }
    }
}
```

you will see that "newLocales" are validate against

```
if (!ArrayUtil.contains(PropsValues.LOCALES, locale)) {
    throw new LocaleException();
}
```

so if you add new locale key, in Display page of Portal settings, which is not in portal-ext.properties or portal.properties you'll get `LocaleException`.

Pay attention that oldLocales are read from preferences (database) `String oldLocales = preferences.getValue(PropsKeys.LOCALES, StringPool.BLANK);`
and validated against portal.properties/portal-ext.properties `if (!ArrayUtil.contains(PropsValues.LOCALES, locale)) { ...`

PropsValues.LOCALES => `public static String[] LOCALES = PropsUtil.getArray(PropsKeys.LOCALES);`

As stated in comment this behavior will happen if (and only if) you add new locale (in GUI) that is not in portal.properties

```
locales=ar_SA,eu_ES,bg_BG,ca_AD,ca_ES,zh_CN,zh_TW,hr_HR,cs_CZ,da_DK,nl_NL,nl_BE,en_US,en_GB,et_EE,fi_FI,fr_FR,gl_ES,de_DE,el_GR,iw_IL,hi_IN,hu_HU,in_ID,it_IT,ja_JP,ko_KR,lo_LA,nb_NO,fa_IR,pl_PL,pt_BR,pt_PT,ro_RO,ru_RU,sr_RS,sr_RS_latin,sl_SI,sk_SK,es_ES,sv_SE,tr_TR,uk_UA,vi_VN
```

or if you modified `locales` in portal-ext.properties than if not in portal-ext.properties.

For example if you have in portal-ext.properties

```
locales=en_GB
```

you will not be able to add any other locale from GUI unles you first add new locale to portal-ext.properties AND then go to Display page of Portal settings and add it there again.

Comment: Moreover, you can specify the language in the URL (adding `/en/` for english, in example)

Comment: I have one portal and several communities (LR 6.1 - sites). The communities allocate several regions with different languages, hence I would like set different default languages for each community.

Comment: What settings might override that portal-ext.properties setting? I tried adding only one option there and it had no effect

Comment: Properties that can be modified both trough GUI (control panel) and portal-ext.properties once they are modified and saved through GUI are ONLY managed through GUI from that point on. So in that case you should change "Available languages" field in "Display Settings". But DO NOTE that at least in LR 6.1 there is a bug around "Available Locales" so you FIRST MUST modify "locales" property in portal-ext (add new language) AND restart AND then add it to "Available Languages" trough GUI (Otherwise you'll get error message "Please enter a valid locale." trying to save modification in GUI).

Comment: I have Liferay Portal Enterprise Edition 6.1.30 EE (Paton / Build 6130 / August 16, 2013) but do not experience the bug @MartinGamulin mentioned. Do you have more info about that?

Comment: @MDT I added more information about bug, and also took a look at vanilla 6.1.30 EE and same code is there so either it is fixed in one of the patches or more explanation that is added will help you to recreate mentioned behavior.

Comment: @MartinGamulin thanks for the detailed answer. I do not have any "locales" set in portal-ext.properties file, i.e. I do not have the "locales=..." row in the file.
That way, whatever (new) language I add from the Portal Display Settings GUI, immediately gets added to the website without incurring in any bug apparently.